# How to add className to a wrapper of a custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having a custom Dropdown component like this:

```
class Dropdown extends Component<DropdownProps, DropdownState> {
 ...
}
```

However, in this **dropdown** class, the **DropdownProps** didn't declare the **className** in the interface.

Now, I'm writing a wrapper for this dropdown component

```
import { Dropdown as Component } from "dropdown";
import { DropdownProps as ComponentProps } from "dropdown";
import cx from "classnames";

type DropdownProps = ComponentProps & {
  className: string;
};

const DropdownWrapper: React.FC<DropdownProps> = props => {
  const { className, children } = props;

  return <Component {...props} className={cx(className)} />;
};
```

However, it still showing error because the return `Component` in the wrapper doesn't accept new props `className`.

Is there anyway I can append the `className` to the `propsList` of the wrapper without the need to alter the original `dropdown`.

Thanks

Comment: There is no way around it. You'll have to add className as an optional prop in the original Dropdown component.

Comment: Pass the className as a prop and add it on the nested component's container like so, <div className={props.className}>

Comment: @ChristopherDias you mean to add a container wrapping the `Component` in the `return statement` ?

Answer (score 1):

Best idea would be to just define an optional `className` prop for your `Dropdown` component. But if you can't and need this wrapper component, then you should create a new props interface that `extends` the one of the original component:

```js
export interface DropdownWrapperProps extends DropdownProps {
  className: string
}
```

Then to fix the TypeScript error you need to extract the `className` from the props. You can easily achieve that using object destructuring. And finally, add a `div` to wrap your component with the needed class:

```js
const DropdownWrapper: React.FC<DropdownWrapperProps> = props => {
  const { className, children, ...rest } = props; // rest is equal to props without 'className' and 'children'

  return (
    <div className={cx(className)}>
      <Component {...rest} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This not working to me, because `Component` is the original dropdown, which doesn't have the className props declaration in its original component. Therefore even if you declare it in the wrapper it still not working ( basically what you did is the same with what I did in my qs right )

Comment: Oh you right, didn't get that `Component` is the `Dropdown`. I will update my answer ;)

Comment: no problem, so far i think the only way is to create another container wrapping the Component in the return statement and put the className there.

Comment: @JakeLam Yes I also though on this so I wrote it in my answer. Not really elegant, but it's the only way if `Dropdown`'s props don't handle `className`.